# Can't connect to remote rabbitMQ server

Tags: rabbitmq

On the server

```
  Starting RabbitMQ 3.8.2 on Erlang 22.2.7
 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
 Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
2022-07-31 10:18:12.381 [info] <0.311.0>
 node           : rabbit@mjcelery
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : (none)
 cookie hash    : kbRAhyQ5I+uDT01QMYXIdg==
 log(s)         : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@mjcelery.log
                : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@mjcelery_upgrade.log
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@mjcelery
```

On the client:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl --longnames --node rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win authenticate_user dubclub "password"
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win']

rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on mjcelery.dubclub.win
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Node name (or hostname) mismatch: node "rabbit@mjcelery" believes its node name is not "rabbit@mjcelery" but something else.
    All nodes and CLI tools must refer to node "rabbit@mjcelery" using the same name the node itself uses (see its logs to find out what it is)


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-459702-rabbit@mj.dubclub.win'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: kbRAhyQ5I+uDT01QMYXIdg==
```

I thought that maybe it was the cookie being different, so I copied the cookie from the mj machine to mjcelery (there used to be a rabbitmq on the mj machine but I'm moving rabbit to a completely different machine, 'mjcelery') and now they report the same cookie hash, but still can't get them to connect.

When I try to authenticate the user on the server, I end up with the same thing.

```
rabbitmqctl --longnames --node rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win authenticate_user dubclub "password"
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win']

rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on mjcelery.dubclub.win
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Node name (or hostname) mismatch: node "rabbit@mjcelery" believes its node name is not "rabbit@mjcelery" but something else.
    All nodes and CLI tools must refer to node "rabbit@mjcelery" using the same name the node itself uses (see its logs to find out what it is)


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-6733-rabbit@mjcelery.dubclub.win'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: kbRAhyQ5I+uDT01QMYXIdg==
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was with `--longnames`.  It talks about using it with the CLI but I can't find anyway to enable longnames on the server. https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server.8.html

When I added entries to /etc/hosts on the client and dropped the `--longnames`  and FQDN node names it connects just fine.

**etc/hosts** on the client machine

```
W.X.Y.Z. mjcelery
```

Then this command succeeds:

```
# rabbitmqctl --node rabbit@mjcelery authenticate_user dubclub "password"
Authenticating user "dubclub" ...
Success
```